# SSH broken in my running ubuntu EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS EC2 with ubuntu, due to a bad config I disabled login by key and by password and now I can't access by SSH.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only way to fix this is to attach the instance's drive to a new instance so you can correct the issue and then remount the drive to the instance.

[Amazon has a tutorial here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598).

Do note that when making SSH config changes, you can keep the SSH session that's editing open. Connect in a new terminal to make sure it's working correctly **before** disconnecting the original session. If you can't connect in the new terminal, undo your changes in the original, still-connected one.